# Redirecting to a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to send users to a static view after they click submit in a form. This is a generic, "Thank you for your submission" view with no corresponding action method or model. Just static HTML. What does my Redirect look like? I usually redirect to an action method and couldn't find the right syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`Redirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirect%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) method. Something like this

```
return Redirect("your_page.html");
```

Comment: i think, you should provide the whole path of the view file. exp: ("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml")

Comment: Since the redirect is sent in the browser, it would depend on where the file is stored. If it's store in the root of the website, your_page.html is correct. I think I would prefer to use relative paths however, `return Redirect("~/your_page.html");`